# Exposing child elements of WPF UserControls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm extending a few WPF UserControl's to allow more flexibility when used in different projects. A typical UserControl contains a few other standard WPF elements such as labels, listviews, buttons etc.

To extend the UserControl's I want other developers to be able to change ItemTemplate's, styles etc of child elements. What is best-practise to expose and "open up" UserControl's without writing to much code?

Both WPF and in-code access is preferred, such as:

```
<controls:UserControl ...>
  <controls:UserControl.ListView ItemTemplate ...>
  <...>
<..>
```

Individual properties can be exposed but requires a lot of extra code for more complex UserControl's.

Mikael

Comment: In WPF, pretty much everything in XAML requires "a lot of extra code" :D